# “don't forget {sending/to send}” and “presents {hanging/to hang} on my tree”

Tags: word-choice, infinitive-vs-gerund

This is a question from my exam please help me. Why and which one is correct?

> **Please do not forget ... me some pretty presents ... on my tree.**

1) sending - hanging

2) to send - hanging

3) sending - to hang

4) to send - to hang

Comment: Please avoid writing  titles that are meaningless and useless to users and visitors alike. We want to create a database of useful questions and answers that can be easily searched for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer is 4) because:

-Forget + doing sth: you did sth in the past, but you forget it

-Forget + to do sth : there is sth you will do in the future, but you don't remember that you must/ have to do it

Comment: I'm assuming you mean *something* when you write *sth*. If so, it would be more useful to actually spell out the word. Unless you're quoting from somewhere. In which case, you should use block quotes (> text) and supply a citation.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is (4)to send- to hang 
"Please do not forget to send me some pretty presents to hang on my tree."

It is a simple sentence of requesting/ordering someone to do something for you in a friendly way.